# What is the best way to use IndexedDB?

Tags: indexeddb

What is the best way to use IndexedDB with ease?

Some library, than allow to use IndexedDB like locaLStorage.

Comment: Asking for a library recommendation is explicitly off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: You can check out - https://www.npmjs.com/package/idbcache. It mimics the apis of lscache. Thus, very similar to localstorage. You can also look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb-keyval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [localForage](http://localforage.github.io/localForage/) library from Mozilla.